# mysql prevent two threads from selecting the same rows

Tags: mysql, concurrency, batch-processing

I have php scripts that process json data in a table:

```
id, data, processed_at
```

I run multiple of those scripts at the same time that process unprocessed rows:

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE processed_at IS NULL
```

I need to make sure that the scripts don't fetch and process the same rows that another script is already processing. I have therefore added two more rows and I use the following query instead of the simple one above:

```
id, data, processed_at, processing_uuid, processing_at

UPDATE data SET 
processing_uuid = '<a uuid>',
processing_at = NOW() 
WHERE processed_at IS NULL 
AND processing_uuid IS NULL;

SELECT * FROM data WHERE processing_uuid = '<a uuid>';
```

Now I can process the returned rows and no conflicts should occur.

Unfortunately I must not those additional required columns to some of my tables and I need a way to achieve the same goal. I thought of a `processing_locks` table:

```
id, processable_table, processable_id, processing_uuid, processing_at
1, data, 1, <a uuid>, '2019-01-01 00:00:00'
```

Unfortunately I don't think I can use the above approach where I can first update and then select.

I would love some feedback or a hint on how a situation like this is normally handled where multiple scripts fetch and process rows from the same table.

Comment: Is the table InnoDB or MyISAM ? if InnoDB, you can utilize [Locking Reads](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html), using `SELECT .. FOR UPDATE`

Comment: if you follow @MadhurBhaiya 's suggestion make sure to keep the needed update records as low as possible.. InnoDB will lock the parent table record/index (better said locks the FOREIGN KEY) aswell including the onces you want to update.. The more locks the more chance a [deadlock](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-deadlocks.html) (can) happen on other clients..

Comment: @RaymondNijland "in an SQL statement that inserts, deletes, or updates many rows, InnoDB checks UNIQUE and FOREIGN KEY constraints row-by-row. When performing foreign key checks, InnoDB sets shared row-level locks on child or parent records it has to look at. InnoDB checks foreign key constraints immediately; the check is not deferred to transaction commit." Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html  .. As per this statement and my interpretation, MySQL should release the locks immediately after FK checks. Please correct me if wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data table is

```
create table data (
    id bigint not null,
    data text,
    processed_at timestamp,
    primary key (id)
);
```

You can create the locks table as:

```
create table processing_locks (
    processable_table varchar(50) not null,
    processable_id bigint not null,
    processing_uuid varchar(50),
    processing_at timestamp,
    primary key (processable_table, processable_id),
    index (processing_uuid)
);
```

Now instead of your UPDATE query you insert unprocessed rows

```
insert ignore into processing_locks (
    processable_table,
    processable_id,
    processing_uuid,
    processing_at
)
    select 'data', id, '<process_uuid>', now()
    from data
    where processed_at is null;
```

Since the combination of `(processable_table, processable_id)` is unique (primary key), no other process can insert the same rows.

Use an UPDATE-JOIN query to set the `processed_at` column in the `data` table:

```
update data d
join processing_locks l
  on  l.processable_table = 'data'
  and l.processable_id = d.id
set d.processed_at = l.processing_at
where l.processing_uuid = '<process_uuid>'
  and d.processing_at is null;
```

Get all rows, which you are going to process:

```
select d.*
from data d
join processing_locks l
  on  l.processable_table = 'data'
  and l.processable_id = d.id
where l.processing_uuid = '<process_uuid>';
```

After you are ready processing the data, clean-up the locks table:

```
delete processing_locks
where processing_uuid = '<process_uuid>';
```